# Metrics for tracking value changes in the database

Tags: java, prometheus, metrics

The database has the value "goods". It is constantly changing in the database. With the help of metrics, you need to track the current value and transmit it to prometheus. What type of metrics is suitable for this case?

Comment: See https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/

Comment: A gauge will do best.

Comment: A gauge can hold a numeric value. So as long as the value "goods" is numeric (you didn't specify) then a gauge would be usable.